# Recuperar valor de input select

Tags: php, html, mysql, entrada

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que me permite almacenar información nueva en una base de datos MySQL y tambien me permite recuperar la informacion guardada y efectuar una modificacion si así lo deseo.

```
<input class="input_mayuscula" type="text" name="sistema_enc" value="<?php echo $alm->__GET('sistema_enc'); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
```

Pero me gustaria simplificarlo con el uso de un SELECT ya que las variables siempre serán las mismas. He intentado cambiando el código original por el SELECT y funciona perfecto para almacenar datos nuevos, pero cuando voy a editar la opción mostrada por defecto es la de la posición 0.

El codigo del SELECT es:

```
<select name="sistema_enc" class="input_mayuscula" value="<?php echo $alm->__GET('sistema_enc'); ?>">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="MRW">MRW</option>
  <option value="DOMESA">DOMESA</option>
  <option value="GRUPOO ZOOM">GRUPO ZOOM</option>
  <option value="TEALCA">TEALCA</option>
  <option value="SEREX">SEREX</option>
</select>
```

Comment: El planteamiento no es del todo claro. No obstante en los `select` se puede usar la posición por defecto de forma inteligente para ahorrarte una etiqueta adicional que indique para qué sirve el `select`. O sea, en vez de poner un `label` y luego el `select`, pones solamente el `select` con un `option` por defecto: `<option value="-1" selected>--Seleccione el Sistema--</option>`. Luego, desde el mismo cliente, escribes código para restringir que éste valor por defecto sea enviado, obligando a elegir uno de los otros. De ese modo, te ahorras una etiqueta y escribes un `select` controlado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que comprobar cuál coincide con el valor que quieres seleccionar en el `option`, no en la etiqueta `select`:

```
<select name="sistema_enc" class="input_mayuscula">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="MRW" <?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')=="MRW") {echo "selected";}?>>MRW</option>
  <option value="DOMESA"<?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')=="DOMESA") {echo "selected";}?>>DOMESA</option>
  <option value="GRUPOO ZOOM" <?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')=="GRUPOO ZOOM") {echo "selected";}?>>GRUPO ZOOM</option>
  <option value="TEALCA" <?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')=="TEALCA") {echo "selected";}?>>TEALCA</option>
  <option value="SEREX" <?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')=="SEREX") {echo "selected";}?>>SEREX</option>
</select>
```

Para ser más eficaz en el código, puedes guardar tus opciones en un array y recorrerlo para crear las opciones. De este modo, si las opciones varían sólo necesitarías modificar el `array` y no el código que muestra el `select`.

```
<?php $opciones = array("MRW","DOMESA","GRUPOO ZOOM","TEALCA","SEREX");?>
<select name="sistema_enc" class="input_mayuscula">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($opciones); $i++) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opciones[$i];?>" <?php if ($alm->__GET('sistema_enc')==$opciones[$i]) {echo "selected";}?>><?php echo $opciones[$i];?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que eso no ocurra, puedes determinar cual de los `option` sea elegido por defecto con la propiedad `selected`. 
Por ejemplo:

```
<option value="MRW" selected>MRW</option>
<option value="DOMESA">DOMESA</option>
```

En este código la opcion por defecto sería **MRW**